# Swift Filter and Map over array of structs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I may have this really wrong. Noob. I've recreated what I'm doing in a playground type environment here. Basically the sender is a slider within a UITableView of other sliders. The myData is the underlying data. I want to perform a calculation to all the items of the underlying data EXCEPT the one which corresponds to the sender item. I have no idea if my closure syntax is correct. This is the first time I'm creating one.

```
// sender comes over as a struct
struct myStruct {
    var tag: Int = 0
    var value: Float = 0
}
let sender = myStruct(tag: 1, value: 199)

// some vars for the calculation
let globalTotal: Float = 597
let globalAnotherTotal: Float = 0

// an array of data structs
struct myDataStruct {
    var name: String = ""
    var value: Float = 0
}
var myData: [myDataStruct] = []
myData.append(myDataStruct(name: "Tom", value: 45.0))
myData.append(myDataStruct(name: "Dick", value: 16.4))
myData.append(myDataStruct(name: "Harry", value: 12.3))

// a closure to do the calculation
var calcOtherVals: (Float, Float) -> (Float) = { (startVal, senderStartVal) in

    let remainingStartVals = globalTotal - senderStartVal
    let remainingNewVal = globalTotal - sender.value - globalAnotherTotal

    let endVal = ((startVal * (100 / remainingStartVals)) / 100) * remainingNewVal

    return endVal
}

// now need to perform calcOtherVals on all the .value floats in myData EXCEPT the element at position sender.tag hopefully using filter and map
```

So basically I'm trying to use filter and map and the calcOtherVals closure to edit the array of structs in place. I can do this with conditionals and loops and calcOtherVals as a function no problem. Just hoping to do it more elegantly.

QUESTION: As in the code comment, I need to perform `calcOtherVals` on all the .value floats in myData EXCEPT the element at position `sender.tag`. How?

Comment: I think that I didn't got it right, you want to map `myData` and filter it to get all data based on what? `myDataStruct` does not has a `tag` property. could you elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myData.enumerated().flatMap { (index, element) in return index != sender.tag ? calcOtherVals (element.value) : nil }
```

Few bits of swift magic here. Firstly `enumerate()` returns an array of tuples containing the element, and the index of said element.

Next `flatMap()`. This is essentially `map` but it ignores any transform that resolves to nil. Great for converting from an optional array to a flat array, and also great if you wish to do a map+filter operation such as this.

-- Updated --

If you're comfortable with implicit arguments, you can reduce it further:

```
myData.enumerated().flatMap { $0.offset != sender.tag ? calcOtherVals ($0.element.value) : nil }
```

Comment: That's not type inference, that's implicit arguments. Type inference is going on either way, since you never specify the types for anything.

Answer (score 3):

So as I understood you need to filter your array 
something like

```
let filteredData = myData.filter({$0.tag != sender.tag})
```

then you use reduce to calculate

```
let sumAll = filterdData.reduce(0, {$0.value + $1.value})
```

Comment: So you're saying I need to add a tag / id value to the myData struct?

Comment: yes, something to identify. 
if your values are unique for example it's between [0...100]
then you don't need extra field and you can use value as tag

Answer (score -1):

This Question is Already have an answer,

for better understanding you can review this very good tutorial about map, filter and reduce

Link:- https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/